# How to Join Tables with UNION without displaying null when no matched UNION

Tags: sql, oracle

how do i join two tables to show the department_id, department_name and last_name. It has to be with UNION.
I only found this solution (below) but that will show the department_name with the last_name as NULL and the last_name with the department_name as null. Is there any method to show everything without Null?

```
SELECT department_id, department_name, TO_CHAR(NULL)
FROM departments
WHERE department_id IN (10,20)
UNION ALL
SELECT department_id, TO_CHAR(NULL), last_name
FROM employees
WHERE department_id IN (10,20)
```

Below is the code which displays what i want to display with UNION:

```
SELECT d.department_id, d.department_name, l.last_name
FROM departments d JOIN employees l
ON d.department_id = l.department_id
WHERE d.department_id IN (10,20)
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: What's wrong with NULL?

Comment: So there is no other way, to display like the example below with UNION right?

Comment: What do you mean by "Display"?  Are you using this for a report?  If so, you can just replace the NULL values with whatever value you want to show in the report, e.g. "(No Value)".

Comment: WHy does this *have to be with a `union`*?

Comment: It has nothing to do with `UNION`. You just need to eliminate NULL values, i.e. any row having a NULL value in any of the columns. Use `COALESCE`, check my answer.

Comment: I am working with SQL for over 6 years and I just hate, how some professors/people at a jobinterview, give you stupid tasks with no practical use, whatsoever

Comment: Well, it is good for OP to learn something new, isn't it?

Comment: It is not good, when the task doesn't make sense. They should have given him a task, where a JOIN doesn't work, and not just forbid the usage of such a fundamental feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make much sense, to do it this way, but so does the whole task.

```
select *
from(
select department_id, max(department_name) over (partition by deptno), last_name
from(
SELECT department_id, department_name, TO_CHAR(NULL) last_name
FROM DEPT
WHERE department_id IN (10,20)
UNION ALL
SELECT department_id, TO_CHAR(NULL), last_name
FROM emp
WHERE department_id IN (10,20)))
where last_name is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a where clause with `COALESCE` to get NOT NULL in an outer query.

`SELECT * FROM (<your union query>) WHERE COALESCE(column1, column2, column3) IS NOT NULL`

You could use `CTE` for your inner query, i.e. your union query. And then use my suggestion to select NOT NULL rows.